# Delete items from MongoDB every 24 hours

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a MongoDB in the form:

```
{Key : "XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-1234", timestamp : 1613776160493
```

I have a Python code to query the database every 10 minutes and I want to delete all items older than 24 hours, how would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would recommend Teejay Bruno's answer this would be a valid solution:

```
import time

dayago = time.time() * 1000 - 86400000
col.delete_many({"timestamp": {"$lt": dayago}})
```

Answer (score 2):

Most databases include this feature already in the form of a retention policy. Rather than manually delete data through python, I would just set this up directly in your database.

A quick search results in MongoDB naming this feature ["Time to Live" or TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)